# Regex match URL with exactly one folder deep

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to figure out how to handle this Regex but cant seem to get the correct sequence.

```
www.abc.com EXCLUDE 
www.abc.com/some-folder-01 MATCH
www.abc.com/some-folder-01?someQScontent MATCH
www.abc.com/some-folder-01/some-product-01 EXCLUDE
www.abc.com/some-folder-02/some-product-01?someQScontent EXCLUDE
```

some-folder-01 could be any number of letters, numbers or hyphens. I've been using [\w-]+ to get the some-folder-01 but I haven't figured out how to say NOT succeeded by another forward slash and another folder. I tried (!?/) but then that just reduced some-folder-01 match down to some-folder-0

As it stands my regex looks like: 
    www.abc.com/([\w-]+)

Comment: Use: `/www\.abc\.com\/[^/]+[?\/#]?$/`

Comment: Thanks! This works great! Will accept answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/www\.abc\.com\/[^/]+[?\/#]?$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AdIPAv/1)

**Explanation:**

- `www\.abc\.com\/`: Match literal string `www.abc.com/`
- `[^/]+`: Match 1+ non-slash characters
- `[?\/#]?$`: Match optional `/` or `?` or `#` followed by end

Comment: Q: How come in the 2nd group you dont need to escape the forward slash?

Comment: Actually Javascript regex allows using `/` unescaped inside character class i.e. `[...]`